# how to convert a binary numpy array to decimal?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert binary numpy array to decimal. Is there a similar function to this `numpy.binary_repr` that works the other way around?

```
x = array([ 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.])
```

I know I can do this:

```
int("110100010",2) = 418
```

But here I need to extract the elements of the array and put them into string? Is there an easier way? if not, then how can I extract the elements of the array and create a string out of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: 2*a+b, x)
418.0
```

Alternatively, as you said, you can construct a string and then convert it to int (base 2)

```
>>> int(''.join(map(lambda x: str(int(x)), x)), 2)
418
```